# SIGSEGV - Runtime Error

Tags: c, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

I was trying to submit this code for a problem on hackerearth and i'm getting
this `SIGSEGV Runtime error`. I read about this error but i couldn't get my code working.Some say it occurs due to invalid memory reference,dynamic initialisation of arrays or array index out of bound.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    long long int f(long long int);
    long long int gcd(long long int,long long int);
    int main(){
       long long int n,q,i;
       scanf("%lld",&n);
       long long int a[n];
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
           scanf("%lld",&a[i]); 
       }
       scanf("%lld",&q);
       while(q--){
           char ch;
           long long int x,y,sum=0;
           scanf("%c%lld%lld",&ch,&x,&y);
           if(ch == 'U'){
               a[x] = y;
           }
           else if(ch == 'C'){
               for(i=x;i<=y;i++){
                  sum = (sum + f(a[i]))%1000000007;
               }
           }
           printf("%lld\n",sum);
       }
       return 0;
    }
    long long int f(long long int t){
       long long int i;
       long long int res;
       for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
           res = (res + gcd(i,t))%1000000007;
       }
       return res;
    }
    long long int gcd(long long int x,long long int t){
       int i;
       long long int divisor=1;
       for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
           if(x%i == 0 && t%i == 0){
               divisor = i;
           }
       }
       return divisor;
    }
```

Comment: which line does it segfaults?

Comment: You're filling in a VLA, we'd have to find out what is the input to this program.

Comment: But yeah, that off-by-one would be one probable cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious error:

```
  long long int a[n];
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++){  // <-- will cause buffer overrun on last iteration
        scanf("%lld", a[i]); // <-- need address of argument
```

On the last iteration of the loop, you are accessing `a[i]` which is a buffer overrun when `i == n`.  In addition, your `scanf` requires the address to be passed.

The loop should be:

```
 long long int a[n];
       for(i=1;i<n;i++){
           scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
```

Or if you really wanted to use fake 1-based arrays (which I really do not recommend doing, since I have seen too many times where there is an off-by-one bug somewhere in the code), you would do this:

```
 long long int a[n+1];
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
           scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
```

Comment: It should probably be `for(i=0;i<n;i++){
           scanf("%lld", &a[i]);`. Changes made: 1) Loop starts from zero 2) Ampersand added for `scanf`.